# Realm - Skip writing nested objects programatically

Tags: android, database, realm

I have seen the use of @Ignore for certain fields but I’m looking for something slightly different. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#models

Is it possible to specify skipping a nested object when writing a parent object to realm?

The reason for this:

I have a complex JSON object which I’m parsing and then saving to my Realm.

This object can get really large so there is some optimisation on my backend to return:

- A complete object
- A preview object

At some points I get a preview user object which returns only a subset of fields.

When saving to realm this overwrites the complete object (as expected) and wipes the fields not present.

The problem is that I still need those wiped fields later on.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the JSON support of Realm? If so you can use this, see last item (my emphasis):

> **Parsing JSON with Realm is subject to the following rules.**
>
> Creating object with JSON which has the field with a null value:
>
> - For a not-required field, set it to null which is the default value.
> - For a required field, throw an exception.
> - Updating object with JSON which has the field with a null value:
> - For a not-required field, set it to null.
> - For a required field, throw an exception.
> - ***JSON doesn’t have the field: Leave the value unchanged for both required and not-required fields.***

Source:
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#json

Comment: I use Gson to translate my json it into a RealmObject after a network request. This RealmObject e.g UserList is displayed in my view. It is then saved to Realm in the background.